# How to add GoogleMaps labels on top of kml

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am adding a KML layer to my google map

```
var weatherLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/kml/qpf/QPF120hr_Day1-5_latest_netlink.kml');
weatherLayer.setMap(map);
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to show labels from Google's tiles on top of my KML overlay?  Ideally I'd show the above KML (NOAA Precip) over Google's roadMap tiles with place labels and roads layered on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not something currently offered.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Is that because the tiles already have roads, labels embedded in them?

Comment: yes, that's exactly why. The tiles get rendered on the fly and then delivered to you, the KML gets rendered separately and then layered on top

Comment: Before the tiles are rendered and sent off are roads, labels etc maintained as independent vector-layers?

Comment: All data on the tiles is rendered together. They are sent to you only after the tile is rendered, however. You have now access otherwise.